# addEventListener does not work on popup in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

addEventListener is a method that should be supported in IE 11.

On previous IE Versions attachEvent could be used or had to be used, but attachEvent was removed in IE 11, so addEventListener has to be used.

This code does work in firefox crome etc. but not in IE 11.

```
    // Popup erstellen.
    popup = window.open('report_handle/print.php?filter_report=' + $('#revi').data('filter_report'), "Popup", "width=1024, height=768, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, status=no, resizable=yes, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no, top=10, left=10");

    // Code erst ausführen, wenn das Popup geladen ist.
    popup.addEventListener('load', handle_popup, false);
```

I do have the impression, that addEventListener does does not support popups in IE 11 or something like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: How was this closed as a dupe of an unanswered question?

Comment: @mplungjan — Because both questions were asked by the same user

Comment: If you want to provide more information about your problem (although, weirdly, this version appears to have less information in it) then **Edit** your question, don't reask it.

Comment: @Quentin - ah. Missed that part